# CSS3 Transform Matrix To Full Transform Conversion

Tags: css

I have a div of **100px width** and **100px height** with the following matrix:

```
transform: matrix(1, 0.5, 1, -0.45, 0, 0);
```

Which gives me this:

[image: The transformed div with matrxi]

How can I convert the transform matrix CSS rule into a full transform CSS rule?

***For example:***

```
transform: scale(0.1) rotate(0.5) skew(0.3);
```

Comment: Edited my question, the question is clear now.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a full transform CSS rule'?

Comment: transform: scale(0.1) rotate(0.5) skew(0.3);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to calculate each portion from the values in the matrix. The best introduction to affine transformations that I've found is this one (even though it's for ActionScript, the math is the same);

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/

Or this one, specifically for CSS:

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/

Comment: Hey onlineracoon, mind sharing your final math/code for splitting these apart?

Comment: Another really helpful link in understanding matrices when not fully versed in (or scared of) the math: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/

Answer (score 2):

There are things called decompose matrix, with W3C compliance, I found on gists https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1340727 Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a more pure-functional version which doesn't rely on elements being on a page? And which doesn't rely on external libraries?